# Why does my code print both if and else statement? Rather it should print only the if output since it is true?

Tags: java, if-statement

My program was supposed to print “Qualified” if the age entered is 18 or higher, and “Disqualified” if under 18. But if I enter for example 21, it prints *both*, which the user obviously sees as a self contradiction. Since the condition `age>=18` is true, it should print only “Qualified”. Why does it print “Disqualified” too?

The image shows my code (left) and a sample run with unexpected output (right).

[image: Code and sample run]

Comment: you have two if statements and one else statement. Use if ... else-if ... else

Comment: Maybe you want the if-else statement inside the first if statement? Please give appropriate examples of input, expected output and which line is printed in addition so we can better tell. Still more important, paste your code as text so we can try it out. Images of code are frowned upon here.

Comment: Everything here is sequential. There is nothing "simultaneous". Just follow the logic line by line in a sequence.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I was nervous too, so know what you mean. And admitted, it takes a bit to learn to [write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (not sure I have learned completely yet). Good thing is you can always edit your question to improve it, which will be welcome. If my suggestions in the previous comment were not enough or hard to grasp, there’s more help for example here: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I have tried to word your question in a clearer way. I am just a little bit unsure whether I have understood it correctly, so please check. And I still suggest that you should paste your program and also the sample run (input and output) *as text* into your question so we can experiment with it ourselves and try some possible repairs out for you.

Comment: BTW the title "...print only the if output since it is true?" is wrong! [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSFVr.png) `if` is **not** true since the age is 21, which is not greater nor equals to `22`

Comment: I think that you wanted the second `if` statement *inside* the first one, so above the right curly brace, `}`, and you wanted the `else` part belong to the first  if  statement. As your code currently stands, `else` belongs to the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because, when age = 21, the result of `if ((age>=22) && (age<=60))` is false, so it will execute `System.out.println("Disqualified");`.

Each if statement can only have one corresponding else. In your code, the first if does not have an else, while the second if does. When the second if condition is not satisfied, it will execute the corresponding else statement.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's better to paste your code directly into the question rather than taking a screenshot.See this [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Now to your question, the else block only belongs to the second if (`if(age>=22 && age <=60`) and not to the first if (`if(age>=18`). What you want is `else if(age>=22 && age<=60)`.
see https://www.javatpoint.com/java-if-else

Answer (score 0):

You should use *if , else if and else conditions* for such scenarios.
I have updated the code as shown below:

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Condition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        System.out.println("Enter age = ");
        age = in.nextInt();
        if (age >= 18 && age < 22) {
            System.out.println("Qualified for DL");
        } else if (age >= 22 && age <=60){
            System.out.println("Working Individuals");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Disqualified");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, you are right.I have modified the if condition ```if (age >= 18 && age < 22)```like this. Earlier also i have added this condition but removed it.

Comment: Better. But now if I enter an age over 60, I get `Disqualified`, which I think never was the intention, though I admit that it’s not perfectly clear.

Comment: @OleV.V. Actually the problem statement is not very clear what exactly the OP is trying to achieve here with these conditions. Ideally ,```Disqualified``` should be applicable only if the age is ```<18```.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to achieve here.

So I will just eloborate your code.

```
// this statment gets executed if age is greater than 18.
if (age >= 18) {
    System.out.println("Qualified for DL");
}

// Control comes here and checks this condition.
if (age >= 22 && age <= 60) {
    System.out.println("Working individuals");

}
// if the above condition is false then control comes to this else part 
else {
    System.out.println("Unqualified");
}
```

There are 2 different if conditions due to which 2 outputs are there.

Answer (score 0):

In Java each if has a corresponding else. So when you did not write the else case for the first if. The control passes to second if case and when the second if case fails, the else case which cooresponds to the second if case gets the control and prints the output as the second if has failed.
A better solution would be to use : if, else-if. In this the final else case runs only when all the if and else-ifs have failed. It is the motive here in your case too:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunAge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        int age=sc.nextInt();
        ageChecker(age);
    }
    private static  void ageChecker(int age){
        if(age>18){
            System.out.println("Try after 4 Years");
        } else if (age>=22 && age<=60) {
            System.out.println("Hurrah You're eligible");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry You're Disqualified");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks wrong. If age is between 22 and 60, you will enter the `age >= 18` part and never the `age >= 22 && age <=60` part.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes I do agree with you that the logic is incorrect. I was just trying to explain him how the control shifts from one else to another. His logic is wrong since there is a condition overlapping that others have already pointed out. I wanted to introduce him to if and else if statements where not all if cases are checked, once even one of the if cases qualify, you break from the loop unlike the usual if-if-else case. I fully agree to your point. Thanks for taking interest in my answer :))

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an `if` statement remember this ->

`if` - Executes the body if the parameters return true.

`else if` - Executes the body if the parameters return true and the previous `if`/`else if` statement was false.

`else` - Executes the body if all the previous `if` statements return false.

Each `if` statement can get continued by an `else`/`else if` statement which I call a chain. When you create a new `if` statement then the previous chain is ended. Which means if you write another `if` statement and write and `else` it will only run based on which chain it is.

**So what is the mistake you are making?** Well take a look at your if statements

```
if(age>=18) {
    System.out.println("Qualified for DL");
}

if((age>=22) && (age<=60)) {
    System.out.println("Working individuals");
}

else {
    System.out.println("Disqualified");
}
```

The first `if` statement runs as usual so it moves on to the second `if` statement. Now using what we had learned earlier we can see that the `else` statement runs when `if((age>=22) && (age<=60))` is false because it is in it's chain. In your case, 21 is less that 22 so that statement is false, which means it runs the `else` statement

**How can you fix this problem?**
Change the second `if` statement into and `else if`. Here's the fixed code

```
if(age>=18) {
    System.out.println("Qualified for DL");
}

else if((age>=22) && (age<=60)) {
    System.out.println("Working individuals");
}

else {
    System.out.println("Disqualified");
}
```